# When and where to instantiate and dispose a disposable property of a class?

Tags: c#, fonts, idisposable

I know `Font` class implement IDisposable interface and should be disposed either explicitly or using `using` clause

I have a class where I want to have a Font property for it

```
class Test 
{ 
    Font Font {set; get;}  
    public Test()
    {
        Font = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);                   
    }
}
```

I am concerned with disposing it when an object of the class is deleted, when and where I should instantiate and dispose it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually a recommended pattern to implement `IDisposable` yourself when encapsulating an object which should be disposed:

```
class Test : IDisposable
{ 
    public Font Font { get; set; }  

    public Test()
    {
        Font = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);                   
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Font.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

That way, you are able to use the `Font` class inside your class and dispose it only when you finish using the `Test` class:

```
using (Test test = new Test())
{
   // Do stuff with test.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, then to instantiate another font from the outside of the class I don't need using statement for "new Font(...)" but for the class, right?

Comment: As its recommended, what happens if I ignore this style in the case of a global class member, such Font example above?

Comment: It will leave it up to the finalizer to clear up the `Font` resources.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Test 
{ 
    Font Font {set; get;}  
    public Test()
    {
        using (var font = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold))
        {
            // do something with font here
        } // font is automatically disposed when going out of scope

    }
}
```

The whole point of using statement is in doing something locally without having to explicitly dispose of an object.

Therefore, it's not really applicable in your case, where you want to somehow use 'using' operator in all the member functions of your Test class

Comment: This misses the point. He wont be able to use the `Font` property as it will be disposed once the constructor is finished.

Comment: Yes, obviously, as I didn't assign anything to it in the first place :) The whole original question is missing the point the way it's formulated atm :)

Comment: The point in the question is how to use a global IDisposable property

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Actually, even after `Dispose` is called on a `Font`, it can still be used for certain things.  Most notably, setting the `Font` property for a typical built-in control will cause it to create a new `Font` whose attributes match those of the passed-in `Font` object, without regard for whether the instance in question had been disposed.  IMHO, Microsoft should document that behavior since it's almost certain that there's a non-trivial amount of production code which--intentionally or not--relies upon it, and there are many cases where creating and immediately disposing...

Comment: ...a `Font` whose sole purpose is to serve as a template for controls would be easier than trying to accurately manage the lifetime of a font which is shared among many controls (better still perhaps might be to have a factory method which would create a `Font` object that was semantically equivalent to one that had been disposed, but wouldn't bother to actually create the GDI resources that weren't ever going to be used anyway).

Comment: @supercat I see what you mean. I didn't know that as im not too familiar with the `Font` class. That isn't the `default` implementation for any object implementing `IDisposable` and it shouldn't be relied on IMO.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: It's a weird and bizarre behavior, to be sure; it would be okay if it were documented, especially if the APIs better indicated what was actually going on, but the lack of clear documentation is irksome.